# Unable to fetch refresh token

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-passport

I'm trying to get the token details (Include refresh token and expired time) from the url `oauth/token` but unfortunately I'm not able to fetch it through Postman which direct call the function. But if i direct call the URL then it will work perfectly.
Below provided my code details

**1. Controller login function**

```
 $response = Http::asForm()->post('http://127.0.0.1:9394/oauth/token', [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => '3',
                'client_secret' => 'V7GUakzjRViTnIP6zryDymYv5tD0dpLxGvhm0gUq',
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scope' => '',
            ]);
```

**2. Postman call login function**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2SJI.png)

**3. Postman direct call url**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5iQJ.png)

My target is to get the token details at the same times when people login because Passport only show using **createToken** function to generate the token.

Comment: For refresh token need to send the token as given in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#refreshing-tokens

Comment: @ABHILASHAK.M The method that you provided is working in Postman (direct call oauth/token URL), but I try to call this function in Laravel by using Postman still appear same error as password grand_type. Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to solve my problem by using below code to call Passport `Oauth/token` URI, Below provided my code.

```
$request = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST', [
    "grant_type"=> "password",
    "client_id"=> "3",
    "client_secret"=> "V7GUakzjRViTnIP6zryDymYv5tD0dpLxGvhm0gUq",
    "username"=> "kanasai1@gmail.com",
    "password"=> "12345678",
    "scope"=> ""
]);

$result = app()->handle($request);

// Capture
$token = json_decode($result->getContent());
```

Many thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56886318/20642827

Comment: mark as correct or close, please. Just be aware that grant_type password is not recommended(Legacy Grants). [here](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/which-grant/) to see more.

Comment: @francisco Thanks for your info, will take note on that.